# Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'scalteType' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting error messages when running an app on debug mode during the Gradle Build in Android Studio. 
This is the error message:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
/Users/ramonsingh/AndroidStudioProjects/Stopwatch/app/src/main/res/layout/main.xml
Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'scalteType' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 10.298 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I've just started building this app, the only file I've changed is the main.xml.

Also, not sure if this is related, but when I go into the Design tab on the main.xml, i get this error:

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:56) Copy stack to clipboard

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you need is right here, before your eyes.

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'scalteType' in package 'android'

There is no attribute called "scalteType" in `ImageView`. Find it in the layout file 'main.xml' and change to "scaleType".